# Sunspot::Rails - how to not commit after saving on certain requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I have a model that gets it's view-count updated after it's viewed. This is causing the model to be reindexed, even though the view-count attribute isn't indexed. Obviously, I don't to hit Solr every time the page is viewed.

How can I keep Sunspot from committing the changes to this model during this particular action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just guessing here but is it possible that sunspot is hooked into the rails transaction? If so you might want to update the viewcount manually outside of active record with something like this:

```
class Page
  after_commit :update_counter
  def update_counter
    unless self.persisted?
      Page.update_all(["page_count = ?", self.page_count + 1, "id = #{self.id}")
    end
   end
end
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I'm hoping there's another answer that's less of a hack.